# What is the logic behind using avg function in SQL for following condition?

Tags: sql

I came across this SQL practice question from this site https://www.sql-practice.com/

Question : "Show the percent of patients that have 'M' as their gender. Round the answer to the nearest hundreth number and in percent form."

One of their suggested solution is

```
SELECT
   round(100 * avg(gender = 'M'), 2) || '%' AS percent_of_male_patients
FROM patients;
```

I couldn't figure out how average function supposed to work in this situation.

This is my own solution

```
SELECT CONCAT(ROUND((SUM(CASE WHEN gender='M' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)/COUNT(DISTINCT patient_id))*100,2) , '%') PERCENT
FROM patients
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Just a note, that site is running a less SQL standard compliant dbms. I.e. expect different behaviors when going somewhere else.

Comment: For me, I am using Vertica. But I am not sure which RDBMS that SQL practice site is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `AVG( expr )` is equivalent to `SUM( expr ) / COUNT(*)` (if you ignore `NULL`s).
- In most SQL implementations today, the *expression* `gender = 'M'` cannot be fed directly into an aggregate function because any comparison expression will be typed as *boolean*, i.e. [`TRUE` or `FALSE` (and possibly `UNKNOWN` and/or `NULL` too)](https://modern-sql.com/concept/three-valued-logic) - and these values are not numeric.

  - Some RDBMS support a 1-digit numeric type known as the `bit` type, however this is not the same as a boolean type.

    - I note that it is entirely possible that a SQL engine may choose to implicitly convert `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0` (whether those are `bit` values or `int` is up to them).
  - In order to convert a boolean expression to a numeric value for use with `AVG` and/or `SUM` you can use a `CASE WHEN bool-expr THEN result0 WHEN ... ELSE valueN END` expression.

    - Which (in the case of equality comparisons) simplifies down to `CASE expr WHEN value0 THEN result0 ELSE resultN END`.
  - So the *pseudo-SQL* `AVG( gender = 'M' )` can be converted into *real* SQL (which works in MSSQL and Postgres, at least) as:

    ```
    AVG( gender = 'M' )
    AVG( CASE gender WHEN 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
    SUM( CASE gender WHEN 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) / COUNT(*)
    ```
- So...

  - if there's 300 `patients` records with `gender = 'M'`
  - ...and 600 `patients` with some other value (ignoring `NULL`)
  - then that's going to be `SUM( /*300 rows of*/ 1 ) / ( 300 + 600 )`
  - then that's going to be `300 / ( 300 + 600 )`

    - which is `300 / 900`
    - which is `0.333`
    - which is **33.3%**.

Comment: I'd expect `gender = 'M'` to return TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: @jarlh Yeah, I first thought the OP was implying that was actual syntax and their SQL engine actually supported it, but after re-reading I see it's just pseudocode, so I've modified my answer.

Comment: Slight correction... `avg` function skips null values so avg of 1, 1, 0, null would be 0.66 instead of 0.5. `sum` skips null too but `count(*)` does not so `sum(x) / count(*)` will produce 0.5, `sum(x) / count(x)` would be more appropriate.